# Bar and Line charts are not synced when in the same chart area

Tags: vb.net, charts, mschart

I have problem with a chart in vb.net. The problem is that line and bar are not synced in the chart area. I've attached a picture to make it clear what I mean

Here is the code where I populate the chart. I´m getting the data from a database.

```
 Dim theDate As Date
    For i As Integer = Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        'Chart1.Series("serRxTime").Points.AddY(dv(i)(0) / 60)
        theDate = dv(i)(1)
        Chart1.Series("serTime").Points.AddXY(theDate.ToString("dd-MMM HH:MM", enUS), dv(i)(0) / 60)
        Chart1.Series("serAdd").Points.AddY(dv(i)(2))

    Next
```

[image: Chart that I have problem with]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line and column series have the same XValues that's why their centres are aligned. You would need to generate different XValues for the two series. XValues that are offset by a small margin. Something like this:

```
Chart1.Series("serTime").XValues = {0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 3.8,,...,count - 0.2}
Chart1.Series("serAdd").XValues = {1, 2, 3, 4,..., count}
```

I used 0.2 difference, but this will be different in your case (especially since it seems you have date axis set?). This would push the line series to the left.

I created an example for you. On the first picture you can see the data for the columns. Their x values are 1,2,3,4,...,12 and their y values are marked with blue.
[image]

And this is the values for the XY chart. As you can see I moved the x values by 0.2 to the left.
[image]