# Extend horizontal line to edges of chart area

Tags: excel, charts, vba

In Excel 2007 I have a chart with a horizontal line (data series) similiar to what [this page](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1265-excel-add-average-line-to-chart.html) shows. But, as you notice, the line starts and ends in the middle of the data point. So, if there are bars on the same chart, the horizontal line will not extend to cover the entire first and last bars. How can I extend the horizontal line to touch the chart edges on the left and right sides?

I tried putting in "dummy" points at the beginning and end of the data series that had zero values (for the bars). This looked good, but the x-axis numbering started at zero and ended at one more than my last real data point, which, in my case is unacceptable.

Oh, and I'm creating the charts in VBA, so I need a VBA solution (which may be the same as the manual solution, just coded). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found an answer [here](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLine.html). This worked great for me and did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

If you right click on the horizontal axis and go into axis options. At the very bottom under Position Axis: select "On Tick Marks"

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar questions here:
[Bar and Line charts are not synced when in the same chart area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201052/bar-and-line-charts-are-not-synced-when-in-the-same-chart-area/22204231#22204231)

In the above question the user needed to move the line to the left, but you can do a similar thing for your case.

Use scatter chart for your line chart. Then you need to set the xvalues of the scatter chart to be a bit different than the ones for your column chart. So let's say that your x-axis numbering goes from 1 to 12. Then you should distribute your xvalues for scatter chart from 0.8 to 12.2. That moves the starting point a bit to the left (0.8 instead of 1) and the last point a bit to the right (12.2 instead of 12). The exact number that you should use will depend on your gap and overlap settings of the column chart.